# dynamic drop down - user selection used for table creation. Is it possible?

Tags: php

ok I've gotten this far with your wonderful help, just trying to work out where I'm going wrong still?

```
    <script>
 function disp_text()
   {
   var w = document.myform.mylist.selectedIndex;
   var selected_text = document.myform.mylist.options[w].text;
   location.href="By_regions_report2.php?selected_text=" + selected_text; //loading a seperate php page to catch result
   alert(selected_text);
   }
   </script>
<?php

$dropdown_sql="SELECT DISTINCT `2010 RSG Code` AS codes FROM locations";
$dropdown_result=mysql_query($dropdown_sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($dropdown_result)) {
    $codes=$row["codes"];
   $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"codes\">$codes</option>";

     }

?>
<form NAME="myform">
<SELECT NAME="mylist" onchange="disp_text()">
<OPTION VALUE=0>Select a region
    <?php echo $options ?>
    </SELECT>
    </form>
```

this is the second .php file:

```
<?php

$selectedCode = $_GET[selected_text];
?>
```

getting error Use of undefined constant selected_text - assumed 'selected_text'  when the onchange() function is invoked

edit:
is there a way to reload the original page automatically with the new variables in it?

Comment: oh I was missing '' around selected text'

Comment: try something like what I've just edited into my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"codes\">$codes";
```

to this:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"codes\">$codes</option>";
```

And I think it will work fine.

Comment: Why would you want the value to be the same for every option?

Comment: Plus, in HTML the `<option>` tag has no end tag, so what the poster wrote is correct in HTML; you only need the `</option>` in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

As a general comment on writing HTML: you need to put the `<select>` inside `<form>` tags and specify the `method` attribute there: `<select>` tags do not have this property.

In this case, however, what you want to do is to change the content of the page your user is currently viewing, based on his selections in the drop-down box. For this, you need AJAX.

What you need to do is this: you need to point the `onChange` event in the `<select>` tag to a Javascript function that reads out the current selection in the drop-down list, then passes this on to a second PHP script which returns whatever data you want to show the user based on that selection. This uses AJAX. When the AJAX request returns, you display this data on the web page. You can use something like jQuery for this: I'd suggest you Google a bit and look up some tutorials :)

Edit: try something like this...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function fetch_data() { 
           var selected_text = document.myform.mylist.options[w].text;
           $("#output").load("fetch_data.php", {code: selected_text});
        };
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<?php
    $dropdown_sql="SELECT DISTINCT `2010 RSG Code` AS codes FROM locations";
    $dropdown_result=mysql_query($dropdown_sql);
    $options="";

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($dropdown_result)) {
        $code=$row["codes"];
        $options .= "<option value=\"codes\">$code ";
    }
?>
<form name="myform">
    <select name="mylist" onchange="fetch_data()">
    <option value="0 >Select a region
    <?php echo $options; ?>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="output">Output goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Create a file and call it `fetch_data.php`. This file will handle getting and formatting the data you want to put in the `<div>` on the first page:

```
<?php
    $selectedCode = $_POST['data'];
    //Do whatever you need to do to get the data you want to put into that <div> 
    //e.g. run a MySQL query and format the results in a table
    //the HTML this script generates will be put into the <div> directly so do not use <body> tags etc
    //Don't forget to escape the data in $_POST['data'] using mysql_real_escape_string to avoid SQL injection, so if you are using MySQL, connect to the database first
    //and then write $selectedCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']); instead
?>
```

For more information on how this works, check out http://api.jquery.com/load/ :)

(IIRC there's also a far newer version of jQuery available than the one you're using from Microsoft: check out jquery.com while you're reading about the load API anyway)

Comment: I had a bit of a look around and so far this is all I've come up with: <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    $('#button1').click(function(){ 
                            alert($('#combo :selected').text());
                    });
        });
 
    </script> which works fine to display the selected text but now I don't know how to pass that back to php